# SDL + OpenGL ES 2.0 to display a texture using a shader

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, raspberry-pi3, sdl-2

I currently need to develop a program that will display a simple texture (which is generated by the program by existing SDL2 code) using a shader. For now to see how it works to combine OpenGL ES 2.0 and SDL (on a raspberry pi framebuffer) I created this sample program (sorry, its missing some error checking and serves as an example). It should for now only display a texture that is loaded from the file "land.png" using SDL2_image.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengles2.h>

#include <iostream>

static const char * vertex = 
"attribute vec4 position;"
"attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;"
""
"varying vec2 textureCoordinate;"
""
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_Position = position;"
"    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;"
"}"
"";

static const char * fragment =
"varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;"
""
"uniform sampler2D videoFrame;"
""
"void main()"
"{"
"    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);"
"}"
"";

unsigned int program_id = 0;

GLuint TextureID  = 0;

bool compile_program()
{
    unsigned int vertex_id = 0;
    unsigned int fragment_id = 0;
    char infoLog[512];
    int success;
    vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_id, 1, &vertex, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_id);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_id, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
        vertex_id = 0;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Vertex shader compiled successfully! Id = " << vertex_id << std::endl;

    fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_id, 1, &fragment, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_id);
    glGetShaderiv(fragment_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_id, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
        vertex_id = 0;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Fragment shader compiled successfully! Id = " << fragment_id << std::endl;


    program_id = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program_id, vertex_id);
    glAttachShader(program_id, fragment_id);
    glLinkProgram(program_id);

    glGetProgramiv(program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program_id, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
        return false;
    }

    TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "videoFrame");

    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING | SDL_VIDEO_OPENGL_ES2) != 0){
        std::cerr << "SDL_Init failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("AnyGlobe", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 480, 480, 0);

    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengles2");

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);

    SDL_RendererInfo rendererInfo;
    SDL_GetRendererInfo(renderer, &rendererInfo);

    std::cout << "Renderer: " << rendererInfo.name << std::endl;
    if(!strncmp(rendererInfo.name, "opengles2", 9)) {
        std::cout << "We have OpenGL ES 2.0" << std::endl;
        compile_program();
    }

    SDL_Texture *land = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "land.png");
    if (!land)
    {
        abort();
    }

    int done = 0;
    float position = 0.0;

    SDL_Texture *texTarget = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 480, 480);

   static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,
    };

    while ( ! done ) {
        //Render to the texture
        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texTarget);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);


        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, land, NULL, NULL);

        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        GLint old_program = 0;

        if(program_id != 0) {
                glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &old_program);
                glUseProgram(program_id);
        }


        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        SDL_GL_BindTexture(texTarget, NULL, NULL);

        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);

        if(program_id != 0) {
            glUseProgram(old_program);
        }

        SDL_Event event;
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                done = 1;
            }
            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) {
                if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE ) {
                    done = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The current status is that only a color background (defined by the RendererDrawColor in SDL) is displayed but not the texture and I cannot put my finger on it why it does not work properly. Can somebody look especially over the OpenGL ES code? I am thankful about every hint.

Comment: Please note: the program works on a regular PC, but not with a Raspberry Pi (other GLES testtools in /opt/vc/ work fine!)

Comment: When you say it "works" on a regular PC, does that mean on Pi it compiles but does NOT run or does it not COMPILE? More clarity please

Comment: It runs, but it does not show the texture.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix-n-match SDL_Renderer stuff and OpenGL, down that path lies pain and madness, [at least at this point in time](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138).

Answer (score 1):

I actually have success combining `SDL_Renderer` and OpenGL (tho not ES, but theoretically should be fine too). If you just want to apply a fragment shader to an `SDL_Texture` this should be doable with some tweaks to your code.

1. instead of doing the vertex geometry yourself, use `SDL_RenderCopy` or `SDL_RenderCopyEx`
2. use `SDL_RenderPresent` instead of `SDL_GL_SwapWindow`
3. you are already correctly using `SDL_GL_BindTexture`, but you are missing `SDL_GL_UnbindTexture`
4. You may need to wrap your "raw" OpenGL calls with `SDL_RenderFlush()`. Depending on if you are using batching or not.

I do not know OpenGL ES, but this is the OpenGL vertex shader I use when I want to do this:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    v_color = gl_Color;
    v_texCoord = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
}
```

This code came directly from the SDL2 source code, so if there is a different one to use for OpenGL ES/ES2 then check their source.